# Cannot pass an array to a function from a multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a Global variable which shows as a Variant/Variant(1 to 33, 1 to 9) in the Locals window. So it's a 2D array, yet when I try to for each over the array I cannot access the whole arrays only the cell values

```
Public myRows As Variant
Public myTable As ListObject




Sub SendEmails()

Dim X As Long
Dim Row As Variant



SetMyTable

For Each Row In myRows
    Debug.Print CheckRow(Row)
Next Row


  
End Sub
```

EDIT: Adding the CheckRow function

```
Function CheckRow(Row As Variant) As Boolean
Dim IsRowValid As Boolean
IsRowValid = True



If IsEmpty(Row(1)) = True Then
    IsRowValid = False

End If
If IsEmpty(Row(2)) = True Then
    IsRowValid = False

End If
If IsEmpty(Row(3)) = True Then
    IsRowValid = False

End If
If IsEmpty(Row(4)) = True Then
    IsRowValid = False

End If
If IsEmpty(Row(5)) = True Then
    IsRowValid = False

End If

CheckRow = IsRowValid

End Function
```

Comment: What's your error/issue?  Cant quite understand from post.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav in the foreach loop I am trying to call the CheckRow function where the input parameter should be a row (array of cell values) yet, I checked the input in Debug and it's only 1 cell value not an array of cell values

Comment: When looping by using `For...Each`, the order in this particular case will be `myRows(1, 1), myRows(1, 2)... myRows(33, 8), myRows(33, 9)`. Not much to do with rows. Could you explain in more detail what you are trying to print? Also, please share the code of the `CheckRow` function because it possibly doesn't do what you expect it should do.

Comment: Okay then, what other loop method can I use? I want to pass the whole array of values not 1 by 1

Comment: In your case, you have 33 rows. So do you want to loop through the rows to check each of the 9 columns per row and if **any** (or **all** ?) of the elements is empty, you want to return `False`, otherwise `True`, in the Immediate window?

Comment: Yes, I have some custom checks to implement, but yeah basically I want to check all the 33 rows, 1 by 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Check the Rows of an Array

- Since you cannot easily pass the rows of the array, pass the 'whole thing' and the row index.

```vb
Public myRows As Variant

Sub SendEmails()

    'SetMyTable ' don't know what that does
    
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To UBound(myRows, 1) ' loop through the rows
        Debug.Print CheckRow(myRows, r)
    Next r

End Sub

Function CheckRow(ByVal Data As Variant, ByVal RowIndex As Long) As Boolean
    
    Dim c As Long
    
    For c = 1 To UBound(Data, 2) ' loop through the columns
        ' Note that 'CheckRow' is initially (by default) equal to 'False'. 
        If IsEmpty(Data(RowIndex, c)) Then Exit Function
    Next c
    
    CheckRow = True ' all values in the row are not empty
        
End Function
```